# Would it be better to write your own rails backend administration pages rather than using ActiveAdmin or Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've done a lot research of ActiveAdmin and Rails Admin on these frameworks.

Whilst they're fantastic and powerful that comes with great scaffolding, I feel there's little room of flexibility when it comes to make custom configuration for my own CMS project which I'll be building from scratch.

I know this is very subjective question but I must ask if I were to build my own rails administrations that's ten times easier than the afore-mentioned frameworks above, then surely it wouldn't be this hard to find a couple online tutorials that would help me to build simple admin pages that doesn't require a lot of time investment to make CMS application work?

Cause I have my own crafted html/css files that I used to mock up the screens for the clients and I don't want to spend too much time trying to mold them into their frameworks and find that later on nothing works as what the client wanted it...

Any suggestions or help you can provide here??

Much appreciated!

Comment: personally I would go with just making the admin pages manually, especially if you already have your own design and markup. Sure admin frameworks will save you time upfront, but in the long run looking for customization options and trying to bend it your way will cost you more.

Comment: Agree with @Saifis. It all comes down to how much you predict you'll have to 'bend' the Admin frameworks.

Comment: Thanks guys. Given the fact how my client dictates this project to be run on a timely-driven basis, then I'm very aware that time is a very limited resource that I could scarcely afford at this point in time.  Thus I need to get more efficient managing my time to deliver my client's project and breaking down existing frameworks to suit my needs will (which I predict) risk me in costing more time and money, when I've yet to implement the other core 95% of the app functionality I have to write.  So I have to call the right shots here ensuring the quality of work is achieved.